# Find correlation between two columns in two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have two dataframes which both have an ID column, and for each ID a date columns with timestamps and a Value column. Now, I would like to find a correlation between the values from each dataset in this way: dataset 1 has all the values of people that got a specific disease, and in dataset 2 there are values for people that DIDN'T get the disease. Now, using the corr function:

```
    corr = df1['val'].corr(df2['val'])
```

my result is 0.1472 and is very very low (too much), meaning they don't have nothing in correlation.
Am I wrong in something? How do I calculate the correlation? Is there a way to find a value (maybe a line) where after that value the people will get the disease? I would like to try this with a Machine Learning technique (SVMs), but first it would be good to have something like the part I explained before. How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your low correlation is due to the index or order of your observations

Have you tried to do a left join by ID?

Comment: it's normal to find a negative correlation as you said they are not the same kind of people. I think that in your case studying the distributions of the data will be better as this is not the same data sample

Comment: so a case would be studying the following: for patients who developed injury, is there a correlation between some values in distribution that caused the injury? And, if any, is there a correlation between those who didn't achieved?

Comment: Yes ! filter your data and see distribution of you 'val' in each scenario (even boxplots will be nice to see) and maybe you discover some patterns

Comment: perfect, I'll try. Thanks